# UseParams For Product Detail Page

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to create a product detail page. I tried using `useParams` Hook but it didn't work out. I'm getting the id in the URL but I'm unable to fetch the item title,image and price on the detail component. I'm using firebase with react js and redux for coding.

I tried mapping `foodItems` but it shows all the food items I uploaded on database. So I removed the mapped code I'm sharing the entire page code here. All I did is assign the id to `useParams` and I don't know what to do next how to use this it to fetch the particular item's title and decp etc.

```
import React from 'react';

import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';



const ProductDetail = (item) => {

  const {id} = useParams();    
  console.log(id);     
                                                                                         
    return (
 
    <section className="text-gray-700 body-font overflow-hidden bg-white">

  <div className="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
    <div className="lg:w-4/5 mx-auto flex flex-wrap">
    
      <img alt="ecommerce" className="lg:w-1/2 w-full object-cover object-center rounded border border-gray-200" src={item.imageURL} />
    
      <div  className="lg:w-1/2 w-full lg:pl-10 lg:py-6 mt-6 lg:mt-0">
        <h1 className="text-gray-900 text-3xl title-font font-medium mb-1">{item.title}</h1>
        <div className="flex mb-4">
          <span className="flex items-center">
            <svg fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-4 h-4 text-red-500" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M12 2l3.09 6.26L22 9.27l-5 4.87 1.18 6.88L12 17.77l-6.18 3.25L7 14.14 2 9.27l6.91-1.01L12 2z"></path>
            </svg>
            <svg fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-4 h-4 text-red-500" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M12 2l3.09 6.26L22 9.27l-5 4.87 1.18 6.88L12 17.77l-6.18 3.25L7 14.14 2 9.27l6.91-1.01L12 2z"></path>
            </svg>
            <svg fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-4 h-4 text-red-500" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M12 2l3.09 6.26L22 9.27l-5 4.87 1.18 6.88L12 17.77l-6.18 3.25L7 14.14 2 9.27l6.91-1.01L12 2z"></path>
            </svg>
            <svg fill="currentColor" stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-4 h-4 text-red-500" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M12 2l3.09 6.26L22 9.27l-5 4.87 1.18 6.88L12 17.77l-6.18 3.25L7 14.14 2 9.27l6.91-1.01L12 2z"></path>
            </svg>
            <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-4 h-4 text-red-500" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M12 2l3.09 6.26L22 9.27l-5 4.87 1.18 6.88L12 17.77l-6.18 3.25L7 14.14 2 9.27l6.91-1.01L12 2z"></path>
            </svg>
            <span className="text-gray-600 ml-3">4 Reviews</span>
          </span>
          <span className="flex ml-3 pl-3 py-2 border-l-2 border-gray-200">
            <a className="text-gray-500">
              <svg fill="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M18 2h-3a5 5 0 00-5 5v3H7v4h3v8h4v-8h3l1-4h-4V7a1 1 0 011-1h3z"></path>
              </svg>
            </a>
            <a className="ml-2 text-gray-500">
              <svg fill="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M23 3a10.9 10.9 0 01-3.14 1.53 4.48 4.48 0 00-7.86 3v1A10.66 10.66 0 013 4s-4 9 5 13a11.64 11.64 0 01-7 2c9 5 20 0 20-11.5a4.5 4.5 0 00-.08-.83A7.72 7.72 0 0023 3z"></path>
              </svg>
            </a>
            <a className="ml-2 text-gray-500">
              <svg fill="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M21 11.5a8.38 8.38 0 01-.9 3.8 8.5 8.5 0 01-7.6 4.7 8.38 8.38 0 01-3.8-.9L3 21l1.9-5.7a8.38 8.38 0 01-.9-3.8 8.5 8.5 0 014.7-7.6 8.38 8.38 0 013.8-.9h.5a8.48 8.48 0 018 8v.5z"></path>
              </svg>
            </a>
          </span>
        </div>
        <p className="leading-relaxed">{item.decp}</p>
        <div className="flex mt-6 items-center pb-5 border-b-2 border-gray-200 mb-5">
          
          <div className="flex ml-6 items-center">
            <span className="mr-3">Size</span>
            <div className="relative">
              <select className="rounded border appearance-none border-gray-400 py-2 focus:outline-none focus:border-red-500 text-base pl-3 pr-10">
                <option>SM</option>
                <option>M</option>
                <option>L</option>
                <option>XL</option>
              </select>
              <span className="absolute right-0 top-0 h-full w-10 text-center text-gray-600 pointer-events-none flex items-center justify-center">
                <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-4 h-4" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M6 9l6 6 6-6"></path>
                </svg>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <span className="title-font font-medium text-2xl text-gray-900">{item.price}</span>
          <button className="flex ml-auto text-white bg-red-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-red-600 rounded"   onClick={() => setItems([...cartItems, item])}>Add To Cart</button>
          <button className="rounded-full w-10 h-10 bg-gray-200 p-0 border-0 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-500 ml-4">
            <svg fill="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" className="w-5 h-5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 00-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 000-7.78z"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 {cartShow && (
    <CartContainer />
  )}

</section>
  )
};

export default ProductDetail;
```

This View Item will navigate to the detail page

[image: This View Item will navigate to the detail page]

This is the detailed page as you can see its fetching the id in the url as well as it is shown in console but I don't know how to use this id to fetch the image title and price.

[image: This is the detailed page as you can see its fetching the id in the url as well as it is shown in console but I don't know how to use this id to fetch the image title and price.]

Comment: please share route for for details page

Comment: In App.js
<Route path="/foodItem/:id" element={<ProductDetail/>} />

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProductDetail = () => {

      const {id} = useParams();
      const [food, setFood] = useState({});

      useEffect( () =>{
        const url = `https://www.example.com/foods/${id}`
        fetch(url)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => setFood(data));
      }, []);
      
      return (
      <div>
        <h1>This details for {food.name}</h1>
      </div>
      );
```

};

export default ProductDetail;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).